# Java Rename file - always append same info

Tags: java, date

i use this simple code to rename a file when an event happens:

```
String newFileName = oldFileName    + "_" + new Date().getTime();
```

if the event happens more and more time i will have a string like:
myfile_1372933712717_1372933715279_1372933716234

while i would like to have only the last timestamp...
Of course i could do a substring to remove the string after "_" and replace it with the new timestamp, but let's suppose i will have a file like: myfile_mycomment...mycomment will be replaced and it's not a good thing...
So how could i recognize if there is already a filestamp in the name of the file?!?

Comment: @Rob013 second time it will have the file name with time stamp i guess.

Comment: Have you tried using `String.lastIndexOf('_')`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `original file name` does'nt contains  `"_"`

Before appending split file name with `"_"` and get  always the `0th` element from  the `string array`  and append the `timestamp`

Comment: so `myfile_mycomment_mycomment` will be replaced by `myfile_123456878` ?

Comment: and if the original file name contains "_"?!?!

Comment: @CaptainAmerica Then you should go for a reg-ex. Most probably the one korashen written.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to approach this with RegEx, as the timestamps will always have the same pattern. By this, you can differ between comments and timestamps and remove only the timestamps.

This code

```
String test = "Hallo_Comment_1372933712717_1372933712717";

test = test.replaceAll("_1[0-9_]{12}", "");

System.out.println(test);
```

generated this output

```
Hallo_Comment
```